# Pasar de java.util.Date a java.time.LocalDate?

Tags: java

Tengo una fecha en Date y la quiero pasar a LocalDate:

```
Date fechaAntigua = new Date();
LocalDate fechaNueva = new LocalDate();

fechaNueva = fechaAntigua ...?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
Date fechaAntigua = new Date();
LocalDate fechaNueva = fechaAntigua.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Extraido de SO: [convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate)

Answer (score 1):

Se puede obtener mediante la clase LocalDate mediante [toInstant()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
... 
...
Date input = new Date();
LocalDate date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explicación de cada librería junto con la funcionalidad que cumple cada una dentro del programa.